# Customize JSON serialization with JaxRS

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

In a webservice call, I would like to return my objects with this JSON structure.

```
{
  "date" : "30/06/2014",
  "price" : {
    "val" : "12.50",
    "curr" : "EUR"
  }
}
```

I'd like to map this JSON code to this Java structure (with [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and [joda-money](http://www.joda.org/joda-money/)):

```
public class MyResponse {
  LocalDate date;
  Money price;
}
```

My webservice currently looks like this:

```
@javax.ws.rs.POST
@javax.ws.rs.Path("test")
@javax.ws.rs.Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@javax.ws.rs.Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public MyResponse test(MyRequest request) {
  MyResponse response = new MyResponse();
  response.setDate(LocalDate.now());
  response.setMoney(Money.parse("EUR 12.50"));
  return response;
}
```

So my question is: where do I register a custom handler to format dates as I want as well as money representations?

Comment: I believe your Jax RS implementation uses some library for handling JSON. For example Spring uses `Jackson` for this purposes, and usually when need custom serialization just need to configure serialization behavior using `Jackson` APIs

Comment: The framework used seems to be `org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api:jar:2.1.0.GA:provided`. Given it's provided, I guess it uses the standard JBoss 6 JSon serializer, but I cannot find which one that is.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) (which should be the default for JBoss EAP 6) you can use custom [JsonSerializers](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JsonSerializer)

For the `LocalDate`:

```
public class DateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDate date, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeString(date.toString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    }

}
```

For the `Money`:

```
public class MoneySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Money> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Money money, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeStringField("val", money.getAmount().toString());
        jgen.writeStringField("curr", money.getCurrencyUnit().getCurrencyCode());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }

}
```

Both Serializers can be registered globally:

```
@Provider
public class JacksonConfig implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JacksonConfig() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
        module.addSerializer(Money.class, new MoneySerializer());
        module.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new DateSerializer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);
    }

    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        return objectMapper;
    }

}
```

For parsing JSON in this custom format you need to implement custom [JsonDeserializers](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JsonDeserializer).

If you are using [Jettison](http://jettison.codehaus.org/) you can do the same thing with custom [XmlAdapters](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html).

Comment: This is some great lead, I could make it work, thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to customize the serialisation without knowing the implementation? I want to stay compatible with any jee server

Comment: Only by implementing a custom [MessageBodyWriter](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html)