# Jax RS build Response from Enum

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

I have to use the javax.ws.rs.core.Response class but I don't understand how it works.

I need to convert an Enum to a JSON like this:

```
public enum StatoPratica {
    A("Awesome"),
    B("Better");
}
```

What I want to obtain is this JSON:

```
{"A":"Awesome", "B":"Better"}
```

How can I obtain this usin the build() method of javax.ws.rs.core.Response?

Comment: You could write a custom serializer, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489186/customize-json-serialization-with-jaxrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a custom `MessagBodyWriter`, also depending on the version of JAX-RS and the JSON library you are using you can do something like this:

```
@XmlType(name = "StatoPratica")
@XmlEnum
public enum StatoPratica {
    @XmlEnumValue(value = "Awesome")
    A, 
    @XmlEnumValue(value = "Better")
    B;
}
```